# gas estimation fails when trying to run a recursive function? Is there an alternative?

Tags: solidity, gas, gas-estimate, recursive

I have been trying to traverse a graph kind of data structure and the only way to do this is by using a recursive function is what I feel. So, now when I try to execute my contract code in remix it works fine when I use remix's VM but when I try to use my ganache as my provider it says gas estimation failed.

Here is my contract code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

import './DEC.sol';

contract DECatalogue
{
    address owner;
    string public name;
    mapping (string => address) dataEntities;
    string[] public dataEntityNames;
    uint public lineageInfoCount = 0;
    uint count = 0;
    uint public notificationCount = 0;
    mapping(uint => Lineage) public lineageInfo;

    struct Lineage
    {
        string name;
        string[] sources;
        string annotations;
    }

    constructor() public
    {
        name = "DataEntityCatalogue Master Contract";
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function createNewDataEntity(string memory _name, string[] memory _dataEntities, string memory _date, string memory _fileName, string memory _annotations) public{
        DataEntityContract instance = new DataEntityContract(_name,_dataEntities, _date, _fileName);
        DataEntitiesCount++;
        dataEntityNames.push(_name);
        dataEntities[_name]=address(instance);
    }

    function getLineage(string memory _name) public payable{
        DataEntityContract de = DataEntityContract(dataEntities[_name]);
        string[] memory sources = de.getSources();
        lineageInfo[count] = Lineage(de.getName(), sources, de.getAnnotations());
        count++;
        if(sources.length==0){
            return;
        }
        else{
            for(uint i=0;i<sources.length;i++){
                getLineage(sources[i]);
            }
        }
        lineageInfoCount = count;
        count=0;
    }
}
```

and here is DEC.sol:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract DataEntityContract {


    DataEntity DE;

    constructor(string memory _name,string[] memory _relatedEntities, string memory _annotations) public
    {
        DE = DataEntity(_name, _relatedEntities, _annotations);
    }

    struct DataEntity {
        string dataEntityName;
        string[] sources;
        string annotations;
    }

    function getSources() public view returns(string[] memory){
        return (DE.sources);
    }

    function getName() public view returns(string memory){
        return (DE.dataEntityName);
    }

    function getAnnotations() public view returns(string memory) {
        return (DE.annotations);
    }

}
```

**UPDATE:** Adding my js code.

```
constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state =
        {
        account: '',
        dataEntities: [],
        lineageEntities: [],
        popup: false,
        };
    }

    async loadWeb3()
    {
        if(window.ethereum)
        {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.ethereum);
        await window.ethereum.enable();
        }
        else if (window.web3)
        {
        window.web3 = new Web3(window.web3.currentProvider);
        await window.ethereum.enable();
        }
        else{
        window.alert("Non ethereum browser detected!!!!");
        }
    }

    async viewLineage(name)
    {
        const web3 = window.web3;
        const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
        const networkData = DataEntityCatalogue.networks[networkId];
        const contract = web3.eth.Contract(DataEntityCatalogue.abi, networkData.address);
        contract.methods.getLineage(name).send({from: this.state.account});
        this.loadLineageEntities();
        this.togglePopup();
    }

    async loadLineageEntities(){
        const web3=window.web3;
        const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
        this.setState({account: accounts[0]});
        const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
        const networkData = await DataEntityCatalogue.networks[networkId];
        if(networkData){
            const DECatalogue = web3.eth.Contract(DataEntityCatalogue.abi, networkData.address);
            const lineageInfoCount = await DECatalogue.methods.lineageInfoCount().call();
            console.log("lineageInfoCount: ", lineageInfoCount);
            for(var i=0;i<lineageInfoCount;i++){
                const entity = await DECatalogue.methods.lineageInfo(i).call();
                this.setState({lineageEntities: [...this.state.lineageEntities, entity]});
            }
        }
    }

    async loadDataEntities()
    {
        const web3 = window.web3;
        const networkId = await web3.eth.net.getId();
        const networkData = DataEntityCatalogue.networks[networkId];
        if(networkData)
        {
            const DECatalogue = web3.eth.Contract(DataEntityCatalogue.abi, networkData.address);
            const dataEntityCount = await DECatalogue.methods.DataEntitiesCount().call();
            for(var i=0;i<=dataEntityCount;i++)
            {
                const DataEntity = await DECatalogue.methods.DataEntities(i).call();
                if(DataEntity===null)
                {
                    break;
                }
                this.setState({dataEntities: [...this.state.dataEntities, DataEntity]});
            }
        }
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <>
            <div style={{borderStyle: "groove", borderColor: "#F7F7F7"}}>
                <h2>Data Entities</h2>
            <table className="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th scope="col">Data Entity</th>
                    <th scope="col">Date Created</th>
                    <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                {
                    this.state.dataEntities.map((DE,key) => {
                        if(key!==0){
                        return(
                            <tr key={key}>
                                <td>{DE.name.toString()}</td>
                                <td>{DE.dateCreated.toString()}</td>
                                **<td><button className="btn btn-secondary" style={{backgroundColor: "#FFEAC2", color:"#404040"}} onClick={() => {this.viewLineage(DE.name.toString())}}>View Lineage</button></td>**// onClick function gets triggered
                            </tr>
                        )}
                        return(<></>)
                })}
            </table>
            </div>
)}}
```

**UPDATE:** When  deployed using remix even on my ganache network, it is working fine. It is just that when I try to use the contract deployed by ganache it is causing this problem

Comment: What is `DataEntity`?

Comment: And please share your test code, since there should obviously be a graph that this test deploys on the network before it calls the recursive function.

Comment: added the js code now! DataEntity is the node in my graph.

Comment: There's a lot to wade through there. Have you considered that possibly the gas estimate is just wrong. You can specify `{from: sender, gas: budget}` when you can from JS and might help since it seems to want to work/works with other tooling.

Comment: yes @RobHitchens-B9lab I have tried that. In fact I have given it 10ETH and still doesn't want to run